# Examples of stop and copy garbage collectors

Tags: programming-languages, garbage-collection

What programming languages (language implementations) use [stop and copy garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_and_Copy_Garbage_Collection_Algorithm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link refers to a **Cheney's algorithm** which is a variant of a **Copying garbage collection** algorithm. As [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Copying_vs._mark-and-sweep_vs._mark-and-don.27t-sweep) says :

> The most straightforward approach is the **semi-space collector** ... This technique is also known as **stop-and-copy**. **Cheney's algorithm** is an improvement on the semi-space collector.

The stop-and-copy garbace collection is used for example in :

- **Java** where the Young Generation part of the Heap contains two Survivor spaces which are being collected by a semi-space collector.